# Set Default Start Document

Tags: asp.net, url-rewrite-module, asp.net-routing

This seems pretty simple, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Using ASP.NET Classic (ie non-MVC), say I have a website www.foo.com that has an /api folder, and in that folder is the file api.aspx (i.e. you hit www.foo.com/api/api.aspx)

How can I set things up (either via Web.config rewrite or via MapPageRoute() in Global.asax.cs) so that www.foo.com/api

1. hits /api/api.aspx **not** /api/Default.aspx
2. doesn't show api.aspx in the browser's URL box (I just want to see either www.foo.com/api or www.foo.com/api/)

I would have thought that this would work:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ApiRoute","api","~/Api/Api.aspx");
```

but it doesn't... I still hit /api/Default.aspx

EDIT:
I also want to support /abc/abc.aspx and /thing/thing.aspx, mostly so when I have these pages open in the IDE they're not all named "Default.aspx" and I can't quickly see which page is which.

Comment: The easiest way to get this to work would be to set your Default Document to Api.aspx in IIS.

Comment: Please see my edit; I want multiple pages, so I don't want the global default doc to be named api.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small demo project. **Each folder** I want to set a **specific** default document I add a `web.config` file.

**project structure**

[image: Project Structure]

Each web.config file defines a default file for it's folder.

**web.config in folderA**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="a.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Accordingly for **folderB**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="b.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**ATTENTION**

> When I did some tests in my development webServer **it did not work**. But
>   when I **published** my project to my **local IIS instance it did work** out
>   all right.

**local IIS deployment**

[image: local IIS deployment]

Comment: The lack of dev support is a problem :(